# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare site_url()

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter and I want to fetch blog post on the my web

Site Homepage When I include two file

```
require_once('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
require_once('blog/wp-includes/link-template.php');
```

I got an error.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare site_url() (previously declared in /home/homebidpro/public_html/dev/system/helpers/url_helper.php:83) in /home/homebidpro/public_html/dev/blog/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 3004
```

I Commented this function according to location  file:

```
function site_url( $path = '', $scheme = null ) {
    return get_site_url( null, $path, $scheme );
}
```

this error is removed and all functionality of website wotks But When I open 
blog is not opening it is giving error

**dev.homebidpro.com page isn’t working**

Blog and project location is same both are in dev Folder.

I stuck till now. Please give the solution as soon as possiable.

The rest of code is

```
 public function blogData()
    {

        require_once('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
        require_once('blog/wp-includes/link-template.php');

        if($catagory !='')
        {

            $args = array(  'posts_per_page' => 3, 'category_name' => $catagory );
        }
        else
        {

            $args = array('posts_per_page' => 4);
        }    

        $mypostsMov = get_posts( $args );  
       // echo "<pre>"; print_r($mypostsMov); die;
        $mypostsarrayMov = array();
        $i=0;
        foreach ($mypostsMov as $post ) : 
        $excerpt = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $post->post_content);      
        $mypostsarrayMov[$i]['post_title'] = strip_tags($post->post_title);
        $mypostsarrayMov[$i]['content'] =    strip_tags($post->post_content);
        $mypostsarrayMov[$i]['permalink'] = get_permalink($post->ID);
        $mypostsarrayMov[$i]['thumbnail'] =get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,array( 300, 200));
        $i++;
        endforeach; 
        wp_reset_postdata();

         //echo "<pre>"; print_r($mypostsarrayMov); die;

         //return $this->render('MovePlusServiceBundle:Default:recentpostCombined.html.twig',array('mypostsMov'=>$mypostsarrayMov, ));

         return $mypostsarrayMov;

}
```

And `site_url` function which is in `codeigniter`

```
if ( ! function_exists('site_url'))

{

    function site_url($uri = '')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->config->site_url($uri);
    }

}
```

and siteurl function which is blog folder I already send you.

Comment: you try rewrite exist function `site_url()` you need rename the function or user exist `site_url()` or get directly the site url by `get_site_url(null,$path,$cheme)` last is batter way because, call function for php this hard and too many function this is complicating(difficalty I don't know how to correct write) you application.

Comment: You can define the function `site_url()` only once. This error means that it is already declared somewere else.

Comment: @peter: What to do in this condition when I comment one site_url() in both site_url() function then some functionality is not works

Comment: I would try renaming the function and changing your code accordingly

Comment: @Peter:ok I am waiting

Comment: @ShahzadBrowsewire Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: @peter: I edited my question posted rest of code

Comment: Rename one of these functions to site_url_two()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110244/discussion-between-shahzad-browsewire-and-peter).

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is that CodeIgniter has a `site_url()` function in the [url helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=site_url#site_url), and Wordpress also has a function `site_url()` which is defined within the [wp-includes/link-template.php file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url).

Because you've included link-template.php in your CodeIniter page, PHP is telling you you're trying to create a function which already exists, which you can't do.

From what I can think of, you need to either:

- Not load the CodeIgniter URL helper on the page you're including Wordpress in, OR
- Not load the wp-includes/link-template.php file when you've loaded the CodeIgniter url helper, OR
- Copy the functionality needed from wp-includes/link-template.php file into a custom library/helper or into your controller so you can generate the results which require the file to be included.

You might choose to implement a combination of these

Comment: Please tell me how to exclude the CodeIgniter URL helper file I don not know. Becaause i don not know proper structure of codeigniter

Comment: There's a few different ways of managing this, but it depends on what you're trying to achieve and what you actually need.  Do you need the functionality from link-template.php for wordpress, and if so, do you need the CodeIgniter url helper loaded?  Similarly, if you're only displaying recent posts, can you not do this from an RSS feed or use the wordpress API (not sure it allows that, I've not looked)

Answer (score 0):

A new established workaround found to fix this issue with WP6+ and CI4.3

change the link-template.php in wp-includes with the following addition:

```
if (!function_exists('site_url')) {
    function site_url($path = '', $scheme = null)
    {
        return get_site_url(null, $path, $scheme);
    }
}
```

This results in the admin and WordPress environment not being influenced by the presence of CodeIgniter, yet it leaves all functionalities operational. Tested successfully. Hope its useful to someone trying to combine these two.