# How to unset any library in Particular Function

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter and Wordpress. I use blog post in site homepage and I asked this question on

[Fatal error: Cannot redeclare site_url()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842010/fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-site-url)

I got some answer that unset url library in a particular function,But I don't know how to unset particular library in specific function.  tried this using unset function but i got Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context.

```
public function blogData()
    {
        // $this->load->helper('url')=null;
         **
```

> unset($this->load->helper('url_helper'));this is possible?

**

```
    require_once('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
    require_once('blog/wp-includes/link-template.php');

    if($catagory !='')
    {

        $args = array(  'posts_per_page' => 3, 'category_name' => $catagory );
    }
    else
    {

        $args = array('posts_per_page' => 4);
    }    

    $mypostsMov = get_posts( $args );  
   // echo "<pre>"; print_r($mypostsMov); die;
    $mypostsarrayMov = array();
    $i=0;
    foreach ($mypostsMov as $post ) : 
    $excerpt = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $post->post_content);      
    $mypostsarrayMov[$i]['post_title'] = strip_tags($post->post_title);
    $mypostsarrayMov[$i]['content'] =    strip_tags($post->post_content);
    $mypostsarrayMov[$i]['permalink'] = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $mypostsarrayMov[$i]['thumbnail'] =get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,array( 300, 200));
    $i++;
    endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();

     //echo "<pre>"; print_r($mypostsarrayMov); die;

     //return $this->render('MovePlusServiceBundle:Default:recentpostCombined.html.twig',array('mypostsMov'=>$mypostsarrayMov, ));

     return $mypostsarrayMov;

}
```

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Can you please explain ?

Comment: Acctually,Milap in my question one link is availble . All  requireiments mention there.